# c++ - Como passar parâmetros entre Janelas em Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, parâmetros, interface, gui

Olá, estou tentando passar um parametro Mat de uma janela para outra, sendo ativado pelo click de um button. O programa compila normalmente e executa, mas ao clicar no botão que ativa o evento, o programa da um chrash na execução. Abaixo o trecho do código que chama a outra janela:

```
void MainWindow::on_commandLinkButton_clicked(){

    Form *form = new Form();
    form->setInput(this->ModFirstP);
    form->execTransform();
    form->setLabels();
    form->show();

}
```

O parâmetro problemático é o ModFirstP do tipo Mat, desejo setá-lo em um atributo da outra janela que estou gerando:

.H

```
void setInput(Mat&);
```

.cpp

```
void Form::setInput(Mat& in){
    this->input = in;
}
```

Alguém saberia como passar parâmetros entre Janelas (Forms) em Qt? Ou o Qt só aceita objetos de QObject como parâmetros entre janelas? Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Yuri, não estou com o Qt instalado mas se não estou muito louco o framework não contém nenhuma classe Form (até por que as clomeçam com um Q). Essa classe Form é implementada estendendo alguma classe do Qt? Acredito que as classes padrão do Qt (QWidget, QDialog, QMainWindow) não contenham um método setInput até por que não encontrei nada a respeito na documentação online.

Comment: Este form foi outra janela que criei utilizando a propria IDE do Qt Creator, ela estende de QWidgets, o método setInput fui eu mesmo que criei para setar o atributo Mat ModFirstP. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Yuri, agora sim sua pergunta ficou mais clara para mim. A maneira como você está fazendo está correta. Resta saber se o ponteiro passado para a outra janela aponta para um lugar válido da memória (pode ser isso que causa o crash). Se puder postar também o código que acessa este ponteiro em "Form" talvez possa te auxiliar de forma mais específica.

Comment: Depois de várias horas quebrando a cabeça descobri qual foi o problema, você está certo @BrunoBermann a declaração está mesmo certa, achei que o problema do crash era na declaração entre os Forms, mas depois de um tempo percebi que havia deletado acidentalmente uma linha da minha classe da janela. vou reformular a resolução em uma resposta para o post. Obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu, fico feliz em ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, após horas e horas quebrando a cabeça sobre o que estaria ocasionando o crash da aplicação, descobri que o problema era com a linha ui->setupUi(this); onde eu havia deletado acidentalmente do construtor da minha classe da nova janela. Após incluir esta linha, o código funcionou normalmente, e o problema nao estava na passagem de parâmetros como eu havia imaginado. Ao que me parece, esta linha que que eu deletei aciona qualquer tipo de interação e manipulação com a minha classe da minha segunda janela, por isso o programa compilava normalmente, mas não conseguia acessar os dados da classe. Bom, de qualquer modo, obrigado pelas respostas e atenção.